# Как узнать ID подтемы в группе Telegram?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Как узнать ID подтемы в группе, и как отправлять сообщения от имени бота в нужную подтему?

Если вписать просто ID группы, то сообщение отправляется в основной чат группы, а не в нужную подтему